# Resize a shape layer with a corner radius, without changing the radius?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, resize

This is something that I have struggled with for years. If I create a shape layer with rounded edges - for example with a 10px radius - if I resize the overall shape then the corner radius grows with it as well.

What I want to do is keep the radius of the edges whilst resizing the overall size.

The only way I can do this is by manually selecting the points on 2 corners and dragging one side of the shape layer. This is a bit of a pain though, and isn't the most efficient way of doing things

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Quick note, in Creative Cloud they allow independent changing of the rounded corners.